# What are .localdomain queries from in my DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am seeing many queries for .localdomain on my DNS server. It seems there are the following types:

ComputerName.localdomain
randomstring.localdomain

Does anyone know what this might be?

Comment: The most obvious answer is that a client on your network is trying to look those addresses up. Without knowing more about the network charecteristics it's impossible to say more, but it could be the result of a mis-configured DNS suffix on a few clients.

Answer (score 2):

Linux servers commonly use 'localhost.localdomain' as their default hostname/domain.

I suspect that some of your Linux servers might be missing a hostfile entry that points such names to the loopback address, and so they are querying your DNS server instead.

Comment: There is also the resolvers search path to consider. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-dns-search-list-for-host-name-lookup/